# How to prove sub-additivity of the Lebesgue measure for open sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a question from my analysis book. It asks to prove for open sets $G_k$
and Lebesgue measure $\lambda$:
$$\lambda \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty G_k\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda(G_k)$$
It asks to proceed by noting that $(a,b) \subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty G_k$ implies $b-a \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda(G_k)$ by considering the fact that
$$[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon] \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^N G_k$$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ and large $N$.

I see how to prove the above fact but I cannot get the sub addivity inequality just by satisfying it for an interval contained in the union of the open sets $G_k$. How to proceed? Any pointers?

Comment: How is Lebesgue measure defined for you? This seems like a strange thing to prove because usually one first defines outer measure, shows that it is countably sub-additive, and then defines Lebesgue measure using outer measure. On this way of doing things, the result you're trying to prove is immediate.

Comment: Well at this point in the book a heuristic definition of Lebesgue measure is given by defining it for open intervals (as the length of those intervals), open sets, and compact sets. For the purposes of this exercise, the definition of Lebesgue measure for open sets is  $\lambda(G_k) = \sum \lambda(I_k)$ where $I_k$ are the countable (and open) component intervals of the set $G_k$. Nothing else is assumed.